# How to use lemon to handle a expression with variables

Tags: c, parsing, compilation, lemon

I want to implement such a program: it reads some expressions which includes some variables. These variables will be set later, and the program should calculate the final result(**like sql prepared statement**).

For example, the expression maybe like `$foo + $bar + 2`, and I need to calculate the result when `$foo` and `$bar` is set later.

I'm trying to implement it with **ragel** and **lemon**. I have learned use **ragel** to parse the expression. But I don't know how to use **lemon** to handle the variable and do the calculation.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build AST for your expression. For every variable in this tree you should save some pointer to a variable (just a name for instance). At the evaluation time, you have to provide values for variable entries. For example, it might be a dictionary `<variable name> -> <variable value>`.

As an example of building AST on C++ using lemon, I can suggest this one: https://github.com/kvirund/calculator

```
veei@sauron:~/git/calculator/build$ ./test.it
expr> foo=1
Value: 1
expr> bar=2
Value: 2
expr> foo+bar+2
Value: 5
expr>
```

But there re2c was used instead of Ragel as tokens provider.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm reading 《flex & bison》recently. The key point is building AST.